# 1 factor column and 15 columns to factor under the 1 factor column then sum each 15 individually

Tags: r

I don't know the vocabulary otherwise I am sure I would be able to effectively search for this. So far I have not found anything and I am running out of time.

So I have 16 columns of information, 1 of them is a factor column, we'll assume dates, and the other 15 are hour times (6 am - 8 pm, representing hour only) with either a 1 or a 0, representing active state or inactive state. What I want to do is

- Group the data by the factor column, (Dates)
- After everything is grouped, I want to individually sum over each 15 columns per grouping
- display a 2 dimensional table with the dates running vertically and time sum running horizontally

Please, if you can help, please use the vocabulary so I can not only learn it myself, but so I can look up documentation and teach it to others too please.

An example would be

```
Date Hour1 Hour2 Hour3 Hour4 Hour5 ... Hour15
9-15   0     0     0     1     1   ...   0
9-15   0     1     1     1     1   ...   0
9-16   0     1     1     1     0   ...   0
9-16   0     0     0     0     0   ...   1
9-16   1     1     0     0     0   ...   1
9-18   0     1     0     1     1   ...   0
.
.
.
11-7   0     1     1     1     0   ...   0
```

What I want is

```
     Hour1 Hour2 Hour3 Hour4 Hour5 ... Hour15
9-15   5    10    15     25   45   ...  20
9-16   5     6    25     28   15   ...  11
9-17   3    45    42      6   17   ...  32
9-18   5    10    15     25   45   ...  20
.
.
.
11-7   12   36    84      9    7   ...  21
```

where each of the entry is the sum over the column variable rather than a 1 or zero frequency count.

Comment: You could improve the quality of your question and probability of good answer by providing a minimal reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: Thank you beginneR, I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that quite easily with dplyr - first group by column "Date", then summarise each of the other columns with `sum`:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 7]
#
#  Date Hour1 Hour2 Hour3 Hour4 Hour5 Hour15
#1 11-7     0     1     1     1     0      0
#2 9-15     0     1     1     2     2      0
#3 9-16     1     2     1     1     0      2
#4 9-18     0     1     0     1     1      0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("11-7", 
"9-15", "9-16", "9-18"), class = "factor"), Hour1 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Hour2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Hour3 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Hour4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L
), Hour5 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Hour15 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Date", "Hour1", "Hour2", "Hour3", 
"Hour4", "Hour5", "Hour15"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```